# How to read query execution plan for multiple stored procedures dynamically

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-execution-plan

My requirement is to read actual/estimate execution plan of multiple stored procedures and want to save its XML into table for further analysis.

```
CREATE TABLE SPPlans
(
  SPNAME VARCHAR(100),
  QUERYPLAN XML
)
```

I am looking for some query which can give actual or estimate query execution plan for each SP given in the table. I tried something like below but its not giving query plan for each SP. Can you please suggest something here.

```
SELECT
    qp.query_plan, 
    OBJECT_NAME(QP.objectid) as [Procedure]    
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS CP
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text( plan_handle)AS SQLText
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan( plan_handle)AS QP
join sys.objects as so on so.[object_id]=QP.objectid
WHERE objtype = 'Proc' AND OBJECT_NAME(QP.objectid) in ('Proc1','Proc2'..)
```

Comment: It would only have it for procedure that were actually executed. Actual plans are impossible to get unless you use `SET STATISTICS XML ON` while running a query. `CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text( plan_handle)AS SQLText` seems superfluous here

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15) to track estimated execution plans along with runtime summaries of query resource utilization and waits over time.  See eg [sys.query_store_plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Or use the  query_post_execution_showplan [Extended Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/monitor-system-activity-using-extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15) to capture actual execution plans to a file.